# Webcore: CFNetwork Loader: Program received a bad signal

Tags: ios, ios5

I am getting the following crashes but have no idea what it is or where to start looking

This happens only in the 5.0 simulator. Not on 6.0 or 5.1.1 simulators

Any help is appreciated.

```
* thread #6: tid = 0x2903, 0x052fe95e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_retain + 4, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)
frame #0: 0x052fe95e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_retain + 4
frame #1: 0x052fec26 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_source_cancel + 18
frame #2: 0x0082c492 CFNetwork`_CFURLCacheDeallocate(void const*) + 64
frame #3: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #4: 0x007c11b1 CFNetwork`HTTPProtocol::~HTTPProtocol() + 459
frame #5: 0x0079a75d CFNetwork`CFClass::FinalizeObj(void const*) + 21
frame #6: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #7: 0x02941af0 CoreFoundation`__CFDictionaryStandardReleaseValue + 80
frame #8: 0x028a24b1 CoreFoundation`__CFBasicHashDrain + 241
frame #9: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #10: 0x007b2237 CFNetwork`SocketStream::~SocketStream() + 477
frame #11: 0x0079a75d CFNetwork`CFClass::FinalizeObj(void const*) + 21
frame #12: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #13: 0x007b1e0b CFNetwork`SocketStream::finalize(void const*) + 63
frame #14: 0x007b1dc6 CFNetwork`non-virtual thunk to SocketStream::finalize(void const*) + 29
frame #15: 0x007b1da1 CFNetwork`ReadStreamCallbacks::_finalize(__CFReadStream*, void*) + 37
frame #16: 0x028b301a CoreFoundation`__CFStreamDeallocate + 138
frame #17: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #18: 0x007bea6c CFNetwork`HTTPReadFilter::~HTTPReadFilter() + 128
frame #19: 0x0079a75d CFNetwork`CFClass::FinalizeObj(void const*) + 21
frame #20: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #21: 0x008502bc CFNetwork`non-virtual thunk to HTTPReadFilter::readStreamFinalize(__CFReadStream*) + 20
frame #22: 0x007bdf1c CFNetwork`CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamFinalize(__CFReadStream*, void*) + 24
frame #23: 0x028b301a CoreFoundation`__CFStreamDeallocate + 138
frame #24: 0x0288b4e3 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 291
frame #25: 0x007be70f CFNetwork`NetConnection::shutdownConnectionStreams() + 143
frame #26: 0x0084d1fc CFNetwork`NetConnection::closeStreamsIfPossibleOrSignalThatThatNeedsToBeDonePrettyPlease() + 42
frame #27: 0x007c285b CFNetwork`HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::removeUnauthConnection(__CFNetConnection*) + 179
frame #28: 0x00864d2d CFNetwork`HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::purgeIdleConnections(double) + 237
frame #29: 0x00861c1e CFNetwork`ConnectionCacheTLS::resetCacheForThisThread() + 120
frame #30: 0x007a9739 CFNetwork`ConnectionTimerTLS::_timerPurgeEntries(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 49
frame #31: 0x02953966 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
frame #32: 0x02953407 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 551
frame #33: 0x028b67c0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1888
frame #34: 0x028b5db4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #35: 0x028b5ccb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #36: 0x00541e40 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
frame #37: 0x004534e6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
frame #38: 0x00453457 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
frame #39: 0x9176bed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335


#0  0x052bc95e in _dispatch_retain ()
#1  0x052bcc26 in dispatch_source_cancel ()
#2  0x018f1492 in _CFURLCacheDeallocate ()
#3  0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#4  0x018861b1 in HTTPProtocol::~HTTPProtocol ()
#5  0x0185f75d in CFClass::FinalizeObj ()
#6  0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#7  0x028ffaf0 in __CFDictionaryStandardReleaseValue ()
#8  0x028604b1 in __CFBasicHashDrain ()
#9  0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#10 0x01877237 in SocketStream::~SocketStream ()
#11 0x0185f75d in CFClass::FinalizeObj ()
#12 0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#13 0x01876e0b in SocketStream::finalize ()
#14 0x01876dc6 in virtual thunk to SocketStream::finalize(void const*) ()
#15 0x01876da1 in ReadStreamCallbacks::_finalize ()
#16 0x0287101a in __CFStreamDeallocate ()
#17 0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#18 0x01883a6c in HTTPReadFilter::~HTTPReadFilter ()
#19 0x0185f75d in CFClass::FinalizeObj ()
#20 0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#21 0x019152bc in non-virtual thunk to HTTPReadFilter::readStreamFinalize(__CFReadStream*) ()
#22 0x01882f1c in CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamFinalize ()
#23 0x0287101a in __CFStreamDeallocate ()
#24 0x028494e3 in CFRelease ()
#25 0x0188370f in NetConnection::shutdownConnectionStreams ()
#26 0x019121fc in NetConnection::closeStreamsIfPossibleOrSignalThatThatNeedsToBeDonePrettyPlease ()
#27 0x0188785b in HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::removeUnauthConnection ()
#28 0x01929d2d in HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::purgeIdleConnections ()
#29 0x01926c1e in ConnectionCacheTLS::resetCacheForThisThread ()
#30 0x0186e739 in ConnectionTimerTLS::_timerPurgeEntries ()
#31 0x02911966 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#32 0x02911407 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#33 0x028747c0 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#34 0x02873db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#35 0x02873ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#36 0x035f6f90 in WebCore::runLoaderThread ()
```